# Keydown does not always work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I develop a small web app. The user can click on button and a modal dialog appears. On this dialog, the user can choose from different options. I used the jquery keydown callback to give the power to use the keyboard seleceting the different options.

I bind this way:

```
$('body').bind('keydown',this.keydown_handler);
```

It works perfectly in Chrone and in Safari. But sometimes in Firefox it just does not work. When I switch between browser tabs, it will be fine. When I click somewhere in the dialog it works fine again. But sometimes I click on one of the option provided, It stops working. The options are images in different divs.

Comment: Have you tried binding to the `window` instead?

Comment: Try binding it to document.

Comment: I have tried to bind to `window` and `document`, but the same result. I have to click outside of the div containing the options to work again or just refresh the browser.

Comment: Can you post more code than just this, or make a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind('keydown',this.keydown_handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to always work:

```
$('body').on('keydown', function (e) {
    alert('Clicked in body')
});
```